# NServiceBus MSMQ Send question

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

I have trouble sending a message via NServiceBus. I have an ASP.Net MVC web app, developing on Win7 x64, I have configured my web.config as

```
       <MsmqTransportConfig    InputQueue="worker"    ErrorQueue="error"    NumberOfWorkerThreads="1"    MaxRetries="5"   />

  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="PricingInformation.Messages" Endpoint="worker2" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>   </UnicastBusConfig>
```

In application_start I wire up the following:

```
var bus = NServiceBus.Configure.WithWeb()
            .StructureMapBuilder()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
                .IsTransactional(false)
                .PurgeOnStartup(false)
            .UnicastBus()
                .ImpersonateSender(false)
            .CreateBus()
            .Start();
```

When the action I'm interested happens in the app I fire

```
    public override void HandleEvent(SupplierPricingUpdatedEvent updatedEvent)
    {
        bus.Send(new ModelSupplierDetailsUpdatedMessage() {Id = updatedEvent.Id})
        return;
     }
```

ModelSupplierDetailsUpdatedMessage is simple class  in PricingInformation.Messages using interface marker IMessage and decorated with Serializable attribute.

The MSMQ queues are setup, not transactional, and everyone including NETWORK SERVICE and IIS_IUSRS have full control (in deseperate troubleshooting measures)

log4net shows the following:

```
DEBUG NServiceBus.Utils.MsmqUtilities  14 - Checking if queue exists: worker.
```

DEBUG NServiceBus.Utils.MsmqUtilities  14 - Checking if queue exists: error.
DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus  Worker.15 - Calling 'HandleBeginMessage' on NServiceBus.SagaPersisters.NHibernate.NHibernateMessageModule
INFO NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus  Worker.15 - worker initialized.
DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus  Worker.15 - Calling 'HandleEndMessage' on NServiceBus.SagaPersisters.NHibernate.NHibernateMessageModule
DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus  9 - **Sending message** PricingInformation.Messages.ModelSupplierDetailsUpdatedMessage, PricingInformation.Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null with ID 2c642672-1bf1-48d4-a90f-734e2fdd726d\8267 to destination worker2.

Yet no matter what I try, and what I tweak (been three hours at it already) the message never appears in the queue. I cant find an exception and i have debug level logging on everything.. Its probably something simple help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that if you manually set up your queues as non-transactional, then it won't work. Setting the NServiceBus "IsTransactional" property to false doesn't mean you can work with non-transactional queues.

Please try deleting the queues and recreating them as transactional or, if you're using the beta of v2.0, just letting NServiceBus create the queues for you.

Comment: Does this mean NService Bus doesnt support non-transactional queues?

Comment: We are now providing basic support in version 3.x but you won't be getting the same level of reliability. In version 4.0, we will be rounding out the rest of that story.